# SublimePythonIDE or Anaconda does not work unless virtualenv workon activated on shell first

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

In my `.sublime-project` i have:

`"settings":
    {
        "python-interpreter": "/Users/dangamble/Envs/cms-apps/bin/python"
    }`

Which honestly doesn't seem to do much, i get no auto complete from SublimePythonIDE or Anaconda. But when i use `workon virtualenv` then swap to the directory and use `sublime .` all the auto completion stuff seems to work.

I'm kinda okay with that workflow but i end up with multiple windows open and i can't use the Sublime project switching as i need to open it from the terminal. Is there a way i can do it just by switching projects through the Sublime project manager?

I'm using Sublime Text 3, Python 2.x & Django 1.7+ if that helps.

Comment: Sounds like you have just misconfigured your settings, if the interpreter is not properly picked up. Double check your settings. Check Sublime Text console for the log entries. Some tips for the configuration http://opensourcehacker.com/2014/03/10/sublime-text-3-for-python-javascript-and-web-developers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting needs to be `"python_interpreter"`, not `"python-interpreter"` (underscore `_` instead of hyphen `-`). Change that, reopen your project, and Anaconda should work as expected.